# Automate data extraction from a pandas dataframe to PDF

Tags: python, pdf-generation, pypdf

I have a pandas DataFrame with 10 columns: lets say column A to J. In each column is a feature corresponding to a point measurement lets say 100 points with point ID 1 to 100. I want to automate the process of extracting the data of each point and their features and then exporting it to a PDF file.

So for point ID 1, the features A-1 to J-1 with the column headings will be exported to a PDF file title ID-1.pdf

I tried to use a for loop and iterate the columns but have an issue with my code

repex below

```
`Regional_data = {'Region':['A','B', 'C',
                             'D', 'E', 'F', 'G','H'],
                   'RO':[5728,3546,2182,3789,1687,609,1996,916],
                  '% RO':[70,77,66,84,85,83,51,84],
                  'cation':[0.5,7.7,6.9,4.2,7.2,1.3,1.4,4.6],
                  'temp':[8,5,8,9,2,1,7,7],
                  'monat':[5,7,3,2,4,6,2,5]}`
```

Comment: try giving a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) paste in your code, then it's much easier for us to help you figure out what's wrong with your code.